# Can I serve files using xinet/tftpd without 777'ing them?

Tags: permissions, tftp, xinetd

I set up a tftp server on my linux server to serve files for my cisco 7940 sip phone.
Is there any way I can serve these files without having to set their permissions to 777? Each time I change them even only a single bit, the file becomes unreachable.

I don't want all my linux users to be able to read these files, since they include some passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page of the 'tftpd' package.

> The use of tftp(1) does not require an
>   account or password on the remote
>   system. Due to the lack of
>   authentication information, tftpd will
>   allow only publicly readable files to
>   be accessed.  Files may be written
>   only if they already exist and are
>   publicly writable.

I switched from using tftpd to using [atftpd](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/atftpd).  I was able to set the user/group the tftp service starts as.  After that I only had to grant access to the served files for that specific account/group.

Comment: +1, aftpd is *much* better... I've found some clients won't even work with the standard tftpd.

Answer (score 0):

I went down that route for a while for my trixbox / polycom setup.  However, full blown ftp was better for my situation... the polycom's would key off date/time of the files on the ftp server, and I believe that tftp doesn't support that.